# Programmatically change selected ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selecteditem, listboxitem

Is it possible to change the selected `ListBoxItem` from Code-Behind in Windows Presentation Foundation?

It's a quite simple task really, I have a `Next` and `Previous` button and they represent the next and previous item in the `ListBox`. But, `myListBox.items` are of course object representations of what I stored in the `ListBox`.

So, how would one fetch the `ListBoxItem` to set the `IsSelected` property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the easier thing to do in your case since you are doing Previous and Next is just increment the SelectedIndex:

```
//Increment
if(myListBox.SelectedIndex < myListBox.Items.Count -1)
     myListBox.SelectedIndex++;

//Decrement
if(myListBox.SelectedIndex > 0)
     myListBox.SelectedIndex--;
```

If you *really* want to get the ListBoxItem that makes up an object you've thrown in your ListBox, you can do:

```
ListBoxItem item = myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(objectIWantToSelect);
item.IsSelected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have various options:

- use the SelectedItem or SelectedIndex property of the ListBox control
- if you have the ListBoxItem and not the parent ListBox, use ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(listboxitem) to retrieve the parent ListBox (and use the previous properties)
- use the ICollectionView interfaces (CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView) and its methods(MoveCurrentToNext, MoveCurrentToPrevious)

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote.  Your answer is technically correct.  I upvoted to compensate :)